# jQuery open all slider elements then jump to anchor link

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion, jquery-ui-slider

Goal: I have some existing content (a lot of text and multiple pages) that I'm updating to hide/segment in a dynamic jQuery slider ([creator's demo page & code here](http://www.snyderplace.com/demos/collapsible.html)). However, the content is full of internal links in various locations, that I don't want to have to update individually.

Solution possibilities I came up with: (a) create jQuery to automatically detect which slider div the anchor is inside of, and automatically open that, or (b) if the URL contains a hash tag, trigger the openAll function to open all the sliders, and then after that, scroll to the anchor location.

Issues: I'm new to this. I went with option B and think my code has the right idea, but it breaks the page. Ideas?

```
var hash = location.hash.replace('#', '');
$('body').find('ul'+hash+':first');
function hashload {
if(window.location.hash) {
    $('.collapsible').openAll();
    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#'+hash).offset().top}, 'fast');}}
```

Relevant resources that might have the key to it all (aka what I was basing this on...):
[Link to an anchor within JQuery tabbed content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595351/link-to-an-anchor-within-jquery-tabbed-content) (and the accompanying solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/TGMDd/65/)

[don't execute script if url contains #](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384796/dont-execute-script-if-url-contains) ...and:
[Getting URL hash location, and using it in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822598/getting-url-hash-location-and-using-it-in-jquery)

[JQuery scroll to anchor on click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508819/jquery-scroll-to-anchor-on-click)

Many thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$('.collapsible').openAll();` works, try removing this line:

```
$('body').find('ul'+hash+':first');
```

1. It does not appear to be doing anything valid.
2. The selectors are incorrect.

it should look something like:

```
$(document.body).find('ul.'+hash+':first');
```